# Efficient approach to transform list of numpy array in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, numpy

I have a list with two ndarray of shape (1,3) inside the list. There are 3 similar copy of this inner list.Each of these inner list is further grouped in the outer list which correspond to a an outer-list with len 3.

The idea is to transform the nested list from shape 3 (outer) and 2 (inner) into the shape of shape 2 (outer) and 3 (inner).

The following code is draft

```
from operator import itemgetter

all_l=[[np.array([[1, 2, 3]]),np.array([[4, 5, 6]])],
       [np.array([[1, 2, 3]]),np.array([[4, 5, 6]])],
       [np.array([[1, 2, 3]]),np.array([[4, 5, 6]])]]


trans_format=[list ( map ( itemgetter ( i),all_l) ) for i in range (0,len(all_l[0]))]
```

But, I wonder whether there more efficient way of achieving this? As in actual implementation, the outer and inner len of the list if huge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code will give your desired data-structure as a `numpy` array:

```
new_arr = np.array(my_list).transpose(1,0,2,3)
```

**Testing it out:**

```
from pprint import pprint
my_list = [[np.arange(3).reshape(1,3), np.arange(3,6).reshape(1,3)],
           [10* np.arange(3).reshape(1,3), 10* np.arange(3,6).reshape(1,3)],
           [100*np.arange(3).reshape(1,3), 100*np.arange(3,6).reshape(1,3)]]
pprint (my_list)
new_arr = np.array(my_list).transpose(1,0,2,3)
print (new_arr.shape)
print (new_arr.dtype)
print (new_arr)
```

**Output:**

```
[[array([[0, 1, 2]]), array([[3, 4, 5]])],
 [array([[ 0, 10, 20]]), array([[30, 40, 50]])],
 [array([[  0, 100, 200]]), array([[300, 400, 500]])]]

(3, 2, 1, 3)
int32
[[[[  0   1   2]]

  [[  3   4   5]]]


 [[[  0  10  20]]

  [[ 30  40  50]]]


 [[[  0 100 200]]

  [[300 400 500]]]]
```

**Converting back to 2x3 list of `numpy` arrays:**

(Can't imagine why you'd want to do that !)

```
new_list = [list(slice) for slice in new_arr]
```

**Testing the conversion:**

```
pprint (new_list)
```

**Output of the conversion:**

```
[[array([[0, 1, 2]]), array([[ 0, 10, 20]]), array([[  0, 100, 200]])],
 [array([[3, 4, 5]]), array([[30, 40, 50]]), array([[300, 400, 500]])]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You are correct in thinking some efficiency can be gained. Here are some timing comparisons.

It's worth noting that these timings were run on the original dataset, and might show an efficiency shift when scaled up. (Work in progress.)

Answer by @fountainhead:
Time per loop: **10.1 µs**

```
new_arr = np.array(all_l).transpose(1,0,2,3)
```

Original:
Time per loop: **3.44 µs**

```
trans_format=[list ( map ( itemgetter ( i),all_l) ) for i in range (0,len(all_l[0]))]
```

Answer by @rapchen:
Time per loop: **1.44 µs**

```
trans_format = [list(row) for row in zip(*all_l)]
```

This answer (verbose/basic approach):
Time per loop: **1.18 µs**

```
l1 = []
l2 = []
for i in l:
    l1.append(i[0])
    l2.append(i[1])
    
trans_format = [l1, l2]
```

Output for all answers:
(Answer by @foundtainhead outputs a numpy array.)

```
[[array([[1, 2, 3]]), array([[1, 2, 3]]), array([[1, 2, 3]])],
 [array([[4, 5, 6]]), array([[4, 5, 6]]), array([[4, 5, 6]])]]
```

Comment: These timing tests were with the minimal demo data, I presume. The comparisons are likely to turn out very different for real large-scale data. At least for one reason -- the conversion overhead might be skewing the performance at smaller scales. Might be worth checking at higher scale-ups

Comment: @fountainhead - Fair point.  your answer is certainly the most concise, nice work.  I'll have a look into the scale-ups.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try zip function:

```
trans_format = list(zip(*all_l))
```

But then each element of the outer list will be a tuple. If you need inner lists you can simply add a conversion:

```
trans_format = [list(row) for row in zip(*all_l)]
```